# Having Issues Running Python in VSCode after installing C++

Tags: python, json, visual-c++, vscode-debugger

I am having an issue of running Python through VSCode after I got C++ to work. When I press F5, the error "launch: program c:\userpathway does not exist". It then prompts me to open 'launch.json'. I was having this issue with C++ when I tried getting it to work but now I can only run C++. If I want to run the python code I have to exit out of VSCode, click the play button at the top right and then it will work. Did I mess something up with the Environment Variable Path?

I haven't tried anything as I don't want to break VSCode more and I need to be able to run C++ code and Python from VSCode.

Comment: "Did I mess something up with the Environment Variable Path?"—maybe, did you modify it? How? To what value? _Specifically_, what does "after I got C++ to work" mean?

Comment: I tried getting C++ to work, the issue I was having was with the C++ complier. The same error as above. I followed all of the steps from this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uz7E--0nOVk). Once I got C++ to work (the code compiles and runs) my ability to debug and run python scripts doesn't. It now reads the same error but with a different pathway. When I go to edit launch.json it brings me to the pathway for launch.json (Code > .vscode > {}launch.json> launch targets > {} C/C++ Runner: Debug Session). Is they python code trying to debug in a C++ environment?

Comment: How I modified the path was by putting in c:\MinGW\bin at the top. Below that path is C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\